# Can not deploy a chart file from spagobi studio

Tags: deployment, charts, highcharts, spagobi

I am starting with spagobi framework and spagobi studio. I have been working with several spagobi birt reports that have been already created and i just made modifications. When i do that i have no problem to deploy the changes to the server.

My problema is that i need to create a new chart in my spagobi studio (version 5.1) to be included in an existent Composite document. So i create de file but when i try to deploy spagobi shows this error  and i can not deploy the file to the server:

> Error during file deploy: Check that label is not already present
>   and user has development permission on selected folder; if still can
>   not solve the problem check Server Log

I tried to create the chart from spagobi management and i could do it from there so i think that it is not a permission problem, because i am using the same user (administrator) from both Spagobi Studio and spagobi management. The problem here was that after i create the chart i couldn't download it from Spagobi Studio. I mean, when i download and i get the document tree i can see my new chart but when i press ok, nothing is downloaded and no error is diplayed.

Anyone knows what is the problem??

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding in Google I search this post:
[Spago World post](https://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/2454.page)

In page 2 there is the answer. It is a bug and there is a patch:
[Web with patch](https://www.spagoworld.org/jira/browse/SPAGOBI-1332)

The patch contains one .class file and it must put into a jar in your spagobi server.
The jar is **webapps/SpagoBI/WEB-INF/lib/spagobi.core-4.0.0.jar**
Then, restart server and you will can deploy with spagobi studio. 
Not matter your version of spagobi studio I try with 4 and 5 and its ok with all.